# Read Clipboard image into function for OCR

Tags: python, ocr, screenshot, clipboard, python-tesseract

I have written a function that reads the clipboard image whence captured as screenshot and then passes that captured image data to OCR engine. I am struggling with the passing of data. The code is given below.

```
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

import numpy as np

img = Image.grabclipboard() #this part needs modification as grabclipboard works in Windows and not in Linux.

if isinstance(img, Image.Image):
    rd = pytesseract.image_to_string(np.array(img), lang='eng') \
        .replace('-\n', '').replace('\n', ' ').encode("ascii", 'ignore')
    print(rd)
else:
    messagebox.showinfo(title="TASK DONE", message="No Image on Clipboard Found.")
```

If you see above code then line `if isinstance(img, Image.Image):` fails to capture the clipboard data and the loop jumps to `else messagebox`.
I want that clipboard content should be read into the OCR engine used here.

I have found that `pyscreenshot` can be of use in this code. Here is an example of the code.

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab    
def grabocr(self, x, y, w, h):
            im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x, y, x+w, y+h))
            pix = im.load()
            for x in range(im.size[0]):
                for y in range(im.size[1]):
                    if pix[x, y] != (254, 254, 254):
                        pix[x, y] = 0;
            return pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
```

Can somebody improve my code based on this one? All I need is to capture the screenshot and send it to my OCR steps.
All successive discussions on Gtk may kindly be ignored.

Comment: Out put is as follows `<class 'NoneType'>`

Comment: ***`<class 'NoneType'>`***: This explains, why `if isinstance(img, Image.Image):` evals to `False`. Where did you get the suggestion to use `Gtk.Clipboard.get` from?

Comment: well it is a long story. I have developed the same thing in windows platform because there `ImageGrab` works. In Linux there is no such thing. So, It is just a trial thing. Can you suggest and alternate to this.

Comment: My result from `.wait_for_image()`: `<GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf object` but i use a `Gtk.ApplicationWindow` with `Gtk.main()`. According to the docu: [This function waits for the data to be received using the main loop](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Clipboard.html#Gtk.Clipboard.wait_for_image). Are you aware, on Linux the [clipboard get cleared on exit the source app](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48783).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have seen your reference to code in some examples. Being an amateur I am unable to get it on my own. I need a little more help by showing this into my code. If you please. The exit problem you have linked to was certainly not my case.

Comment: The whole thing is stuck on just one thing. There is no equivalent to ImageGrab from the Pillow library in Linux. Something which works smoothly in windows. I need an alternative to ImageGrab to be used here.

Comment: Try [Tutorial - Clipboard](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clipboard.html)

Comment: thanks, I have seen this. But it is not for Tkinter.

Comment: ***"But it is not for Tkinter"***: Is it working for you as it is?

Comment: I never used GTk, I used pillow libraries to handle clipboard. So, of course it is not working.

Comment: Read [ImageGrab Module (macOS and Windows only)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageGrab.html?highlight=imagegrab)

Comment: that's what exactly my point is. I have already implemented this in windows now I want to develop a Linux version, ImageGrab does not work in Linux.